# Width of inputs in inline form - Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

Good morning,
I am trying to set up a inline form with inputs of different widths using Bootstrap 4. I have tried the different options available here: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/.

This is as far as I went:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <label for="exampleInputName2" class="col-form-label">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-xs-4">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I am not using any form classes or tags.

----------------  EDIT ------------------------

To be more specific, how would you specify the widths of labels and inputs in this example coming from the Bootstrap 4 website?

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```

Any good and simple example would be welcome.

Thanks

Sylvain

Comment: What is the question? Your example has "inline form with inputs of different widths"... http://codeply.com/go/yYFKb5XkVT

Comment: @ZimSystem It could effectivelly work but it's not. For example, the 2 inputs col-xs-3 and col-xs-4 have exactly the same width, so I am missing something. So I am just looking for best practice advice using the form-inline tag.

Comment: col-xs-3 and col-xs-4 appear different width for me.. the col-xs-4 being wider

Answer (score 24):

you could also use the Bootstrap 4 width utilities : (.w-25, .w-50, .w-75, .w-100, .mw-100)

```
<input type="some_type" class="form-control w-25">
```

Answer (score 9):

See the example below, if you want to use bootstrap v4 grid widths along with the `form-inline`

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <p class="form-control-static">email@example.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm identity</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Check the fiddle for more details: https://jsfiddle.net/dx0dzaqj/1/

Answer (score 5):

To make the input takes all the available remaining width, set the input as

```
display:flex;
flex-grow:1
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete `xs` from `col-*` class, for example change `col-xs-2` into `col-2`. `col-xs-*` is for Bootstrap 3 and not BS 4.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example. 
Wrap it in a form element and you can add different inputs. 
Better to keep the col-xs- classes uniform so that they line up correctly

Make sure you have added the bootstrap css and js to your site.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MIwDKRSSImVFAZCVLtU0LMDdON6KVCrZHyVQQj6e8wIEJkW4tvwqXrbMIya1vriY" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ux8v3A6CPtOTqOzMKiuo3d/DomGaaClxFYdCu2HPMBEkf6x2xiDyJ7gkXU0MWwaD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name1" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder=".col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name2" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Other Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name2" placeholder=".col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="name3" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Third Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name3" placeholder=".col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: this form is not inline

Comment: The code snippet throws an error